# Postgres: Iterate argument array within dollar quoted function definition and change returned table columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function like [in pseudo-code]...

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(
  strings TEXT[]
) 
RETURNS (
  id,
  user_information,
  string1,
  string2,
  string3
) AS $$ 
  BEGIN RETURN QUERY
    ...
```

Where `string1`, `string2`, and `string3` are the elements of the `strings` array.

Each element of the array points to a series of data which determines which Boolean value to give based on `id`.

I **NEED** the columns to be as written. If it weren't for that, I'd look into returning and array. How can this be done?

I'm a POSTGRES novice.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned any details of the table you are pulling information from or how the logic is supposed to work.

If the size of the array is fixed and known beforehand, you can use

```
SELECT id, user_information, strings[1], strings[2], strings[3]
  FROM array_test
```

Here's the result of the query

```
id | user_information | strings | strings | strings 
---+------------------+---------+---------+---------
 1 | "tom jones"      | "apple" | "banana"| "pear"
 2 | "billy idol"     | "orange"| "cherry"| "strawberry"
```

I used this table:

```
CREATE TABLE array_test
(
  id serial,
  user_information text,
  strings text[]
)
```

and this data

```
BEGIN;
insert into array_test 
(user_information, strings) 
values('tom jones', array['apple', 'banana', 'pear']);
insert into array_test 
(user_information, strings) 
values('bill idol', array['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry']);
COMMIT;
```